# C# Definir orientação da página de um controle WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Olá.
Referente: Windows Forms.

Tenho um controle WebBrowser num formulário que é exibido para o usuário. Este WebBrowser exibe um documento HTML na sua propriedade DocumentText. Consigo exibir o formulário perfeitamente, porém ao imprimir a **orientação: Paisagem** é o que quero definir.

O que já tentei:
Criar um controle PrintDocument e atribuir o HTML do WebBrowser, assim conseguiria configurar a página nas propriedades do PrintDocument. Infelizmente não é possível transferir de uma String para Drawing.PrintDocument;

*O que talvez resolva, não sei se estou no caminho correto:
Um controle PrintDialog que receberá as configurações de página. Aparentemente é necessário um PrintDocument com as configurações de página, mas retorno ao problema do paragráfo anterior*

Abaixo o código que exibe o formulário, onde dHTML é da Classe StringBuilder:

```
FrmVisualizadorHTML f = new FrmVisualizadorHTML(dHTML.ToString());
f.ShowDialog();
```

Formulário FrmVisualizadorHTML

```
    public partial class FrmVisualizadorHTML : Form
    {
        private string DocHtml;
        public FrmVisualizadorHTML(string HtmlParaMostrar)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DocHtml = HtmlParaMostrar;
        }

        private void FrmVisualizadorHTML_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser.DocumentText = DocHtml;
            
        }
    }
```

Estou imprimindo o documento através do atalho padrão Crtl+P.

Answer (score 0):

Leandro, ao tentar imprimir pela impressora virtual PDF escolha a orientação (Paisagem)
me diga se funciona dessa forma.